# OpenType GPOS LookupType 8 - skipping marks

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

I am trying to understand the rendering of "بڑ" (Urdu - Unicode 1576, 1681) with a font [Jameel_Noori_Nastaleeq.ttf](http://www.urdujahan.com/font.html).

The string is converted into glyphs [607, 460, 471, 1651] by the GSUB table. I can detect the correct anchor-attachment of the second glyph under the first one. But I can not find an appropriate GSUB subtable, that would position the third glyph on top of the first one. Here, the left one is correct, the right one is what my program does at the moment.

[image]

Also, I don't quite understand the LookupType 8 of GSUB. Some LookupTable can have LookupFlags including a bit 8 - ignoreMarks. When matching the Backtrack, Input and Lookahead sequences, should I take these flags into account, i.e. skip marks? What exactly is the mechanism of matching and applying LookupType 8?

Comment: You 100% want to ask this question over on https://typedrawers.com, rather than here. OpenType programming is a super niche subject, and typedrawers.com is full of literally all the people that worked on shaping the opentype spec itself, knowledge exactly what you're asking about and able to give you a way more detailed answer than almost anyone on SO could give you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The positioning of both marks (the small tah, and dot of 'beh') is done through a lookup in the Mark Positioning ('mark') feature of the **GPOS** table, which is applied *after* the GSUB rules are applied. There is no GSUB-only way to get the correct final positioning. The GPOS must be processed (after the GSUB).

As to the ignoreMarks flag: the flag isn't specific to GSUB LookupType8. Any lookup (GSUB or GPOS) can set this flag. It tells the layout engine to ignore marks in the sequence under consideration, for purposes of matching context. This allows defining substitution contexts with only the "root" glyphs of a sequence, so if the context rule is `A B C`, a lookup with the ignoreMarks flag set would match `A (mark) B C`, `A B (mark) C`, `A B C`, etc.

It comes into play in this font because first the two input characters are decomposed (in the GSUB) to a sequence of base + mark glyphs, then recomposed (also in the GSUB), then the marks are positioned (in the GPOS).

(as an aside: why are you doing text layout yourself, as opposed to using an existing layout engine, such as HarfBuzz or engines built in to other operating systems?)

Comment: Hi, I am making a photo editor www.Photopea.com, that works in a browser and is used by 100 000 people every day. Sadly, there is no OpenType layout engine in Javascript, so I had to make my own called Typr.js . It is already quite advanced, but as my photo editor expands, I have to gradually add missing parts (like rendering Urdu etc).

Comment: so could you tell me, which lookup table is responsible for repositioning the "tiny b"? The "mark" feature mentions 15 lookup records, and I can not match it with any of them :(

Comment: Have a look at GPOS lookupList index #20. That is the lookup referenced by the 'mark' feature which positions both the dot and the small tah ("tiny b"). It's actually a mark-to-ligature lookup (GPOS lookupType 5).

Comment: Oh, and check out https://github.com/prezi/harfbuzz-js which claims to be a JavaScript implementation of HarfBuzz (via Emscripten). Sounds like the project could use some help, and the hard part (OpenType Layout logic) is already done.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I have been discussing it here in parallel: https://typedrawers.com/discussion/comment/40179#Comment_40179

Comment: Sure thing. There are actually some of us here on StackOverflow who know this stuff, too ;-)

Comment: So when looking for a preceding ligature glyph (for which this Mark-To-Ligature lookup is defined), we should skip all preceding mark glyphs? Even when the "ignoreMarks" flag of the lookup is not set (as it is not set in case of index #20)?

Comment: Also, it seems like my renerer is ignoring spaces. GSUB converts spaces into glyphs, which have advance width (hmtx) Zero. Here is how Urdu looks like in a Chrome browser (top) and my custom renderer (bottom): https://imgur.com/MjlimFu . Which one is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190862/discussion-between-djangodude-and-ivan-kuckir).